# "Leader" en el contexto de una empresa

Tags: traducción

Cómo se dice "leader" en el contexto de una empresa en español?

Por Ejemplo, en ingles dicen:

> "Apple is a leader in the smartphone market"

Pero en español creo *líder* solo es para persones.

Comment: Es exactament lo mismo: _Apple es el líder en el mercado de los telefonos inteligentes (o smartphones)._

Comment: O también podrías decir _Apple es la empresa líder en el mercado de los teléfonos inteligentes_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No hay ningún problema , tienes otras dos definiciones en la RAE

Parte de la tercera definición: *indica que lo designado va en cabeza entre los de su clase*.

- Apple es líder del mercado tecnológico
- Esta postura filosófica lideró el pensamiento europeo durante medio siglo.

Segunda definición: *Persona o equipo que va a la cabeza de una competición deportiva.*

- Nuestro equipo lidera en solitario el campeonato de fútbol.
- El futbolista lidera la lista de goleadores.

Y la primera que es la que mencionas: *Persona a la que un grupo sigue, reconociéndola como jefe u orientadora.*

- Él lidera a los ciclistas del pelotón.
- El capitán lideró el ejercito contra los invasores.
- Él es el líder de la pandilla.